# If $X\ge 0$ and $a\ge E[X]$, then $P(X\gt a)\ge (E(X)-a)^2/ E(X^2)$

Tags: probability, inequality, expectation

I need help with this problem.

Prove that if $X\ge0$ and $E[X^2]<\infty$ then for all $a\neq0$, $E[X] > a$, we have $$P(X\gt a)\ge\frac {(E(X)-a)^2}{E(X^2)}$$

#### Progress

I have my doubts if this problem is true, but I need your help to confirm it.

#### Edit:

I think the problem works when we set $E[X] > a $. Previously it was  $E[X] \leq a $.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{E}[X] \leq a$ and $X \geq 0$, it follows that $\mathbb{E}[X] \geq 0$, so that $a \geq 0$. I would recommend looking at the one-sided Chebyshev inequality.

Comment: Are you sure this is true? Take a Bernoulli with parameter $1$ ($\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X^2] = 1$), and $a=1000$...

Comment: Of course, there is also the possibility that it's not true...

Comment: I have my doubts if this problem is true, but I need you help to confirm it.

Comment: In the version I have formulated with $E[X] > a$, you may be able to show this if you use the Cauchy Schwarz inequality for probability. Let $I$ be the indicator random variable. $E[X] = E[X*I(X >a) ] + E[X*I(X<a)]$
Then we should be able to argue $E[X] - a \leq E[X*I(X>a)] $.

Then by Cauchy-Schwarz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated, the statement seems false. Tacking $X$ to be a Bernoulli with parameter $p=1$ ($X=1$ a.s.; $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X^2] = 1$), that would mean that for all $a\geq 1$
$$
0 = \Pr[X > a] \geq (a-1)^2 \geq 0\ .
$$

Comment: Don't you think $$0=Pr[X\gt a]\ge 0$$ is true?

Comment: @AlexandraDang you ask that the inequality holds for all $a \neq 0$. If you take $a >1$, then Clement's inequality shows that $0 =P[X>a] \ge (a-1)^{2}> 0$, *i.e.*, $0>0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @AlexandraDang as m.a. pointed, I do think the inequality above holds exactly for *one* value of $a \geq 1$.

Comment: oops, I totally skip the words "for all". Thank you guys!